DMR Physical RF connectivity
I am new to RF. I have to design a DMR system with a base station connected to 2 antennas looking in opposite directions.  the operating freq band is 160MHz. The antenna is 6 element yagi and the radio base station used is leornado ECOS-E DTA7000 Multi-mode Base Station. it has one tx port and one rx port. i know that i can use a duplexer to connect the antenna to the base station to use it in both tx and rx mode. but in this way i am able to connect only one antenna. how would i connect two antennas to the same base station ??
excuse me for my ignorance, but your suggestions would be very helpful.
thank u in advance.

I think you're looking for a splitter/combiner that will accept the feed-lines from both yagis on one end, and the feed line from your duplexer on the other end.
You'll need to be very intentional about the placement and phasing of the yagis so that their signals don't interfere in unintended ways.
Also, splitting the tx signal this way means roughly half the power going out each antenna (assuming near ideal conditions); keep this in mind when estimating coverage in your design.
